# Simplifying logarithmic equation $0.1 = e ^{-(\ln 2)t/5700}$?

Tags: calculus

$$0.1 = e ^{-(\ln 2)t/5700}$$

How do I simplify this? I took the ln of both sides so does the $e^{\ln}$ cancel out?

$$\ln 0.1 = \ln e ^{-(\ln 2)t/5700}$$
$$-2.3 = \ln e ^{-(\ln 2)t/5700}$$

but the $\ln$ in the exponent can't just disappear?

Comment: Jessica, you may want to try using latex formatting in your posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but using the fact that $$\ln{e^x} = x$$ for all $x$, we see that

$$\ln{0.1} = \ln e^{(-\ln{2}) t / 5700} = \frac{(-\ln{2}) t}{5700}$$

Hence

$$t = \frac{5700 \ln{0.1}}{-\ln{2}}$$

Comment: I can't accept your answer for another 9 min, but gosh was that easy! Thank you!

Comment: @Jessica You're very welcome.